# Salesforce access check warnings

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

[image: Salesforce access check erros]

Suddenly access check warnings have started popping up in my browser's console. This started happening this week only. I have been working on this application for past 2 weeks and I never saw a single warning. Is it because of any upgrades to salesforce lightning? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Ashishnarkhede I am having this problem too and I REALLY need an answer as to why it is occurring. I suspect it is a bug in the software, but I was wondering if you found a fix since you reported this a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of relevant articles:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_access_warnings.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

These are not a bug in salesforce (generally at least), but rather stepping up enforcement on the lightning component system's access controls. I have been told that at some point these will become firm errors, rather than just warnings, so **I would strongly advise you to take them seriously.**

Make sure that anytime you set an attribute on the view of a component there is an aura:attribute tag. You can not define new view attributes at runtime, although you can define an attribute of type Object and dynamically add any properties you want to *that.*